# Is there a Javascript library for localStorage to emulate SQLite

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, local-storage

I have an application which uses SQLite for storage.  We need to change it to enable it to work with Firefox and other browsers.

LocalStorage seems to be the choice.  However, localStorage does not offer the more complex sql functionality (for example OrderBy, GroupBy, table joins etc.).

Would anyone know of a Javascript existing library that would work with localStorage and make it behave more like SQL?  -Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You could use one of the javascript linq implementations. They get their data from plain javascript objects/arrays, so that should make interfacing with localstorage pretty much cake.

http://jslinq.codeplex.com/
http://linqjs.codeplex.com/
or even http://www.thomasfrank.se/sqlike.html

online demo for them: http://secretgeek.net/JsLinq/ (note the options on the top left)

I'm not so sure about the insert/update aspects, but you can sure do some nice data querying with them.

Comment: thanks so much for your input. sqlike seems to be perfect, however, it seems that it only works with arrays. Is there a wrapper like sqlike for localStorage that you know of ?

Comment: localstorage works fine with arrays? `localStorage['foo'] = [1,2,3];`

Answer (score 8):

Try [sql.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js). This is a direct port of SQLite from native C to pure javascript.

Comment: this is a really nice option.

Answer (score 4):

Try [alasql.js](https://github.com/agershun/alasql). This is a SQL database written on pure JavaScript. Even it does not have functionality to work with locasStorage, but you can easily save and restore all data you need before and after the session or changes.

Here is an example how to use Alasql with localStorage:

```
// Create database and table structure
var db = new alasql.Database();
db.exec('CREATE TABLE students (studentid INT, school STRING)');

// Load table data from localStorage if it exists or create new table
if(localStorage['students']) {
    db.tables.students.data = JSON.parse(localStorage['students']);
} else {
    db.tables.students.data = [
       {studentid: 55, school: 'abc'},
       {studentid: 56, school: 'klm'},
       {studentid: 57, school: 'nyz'}
    ];
    localStorage['students'] = JSON.stringify(db.tables.students.data);
};

// Add new student and save database
db.tables.students.data.push({student: 100, school:'qwe'}); 
localStorage['students'] = JSON.stringify(db.tables.students.data);

// SQL-query
console.log(db.exec("SELECT * FROM students WHERE school > 'ght'"));
```

This example [in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6a06dqhc/3/).

Comment: Now Alasql has internal support of lacalStorage (see the sample in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/x1gq3wf2/)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for an HTML5 / JavaScript Relational Database alternative to SQLLite:  [SequelSphere](http://www.sequelsphere.com)

SequelSphere is a Javascript library that works across all modern browsers and platforms, and stores its data in IndexedDB and LocalStorage (depending on what the browser supports).  It easily integrates with any 3rd party RIA framework, and provides "change trackers" to help with data synchronization.

Since you asked about complex SELECT capabilities, the following is found on SequelSphere's site under: [Top 9 Cool SequelSphere Features](http://www.sequelsphere.com/how-it-works/top-features/)

> The most impressive feature of SequelSphere has to be its
>   revolutionary SQL parsing and execution engine. It handles all normal
>   SELECT features and expressions, and then goes beyond handling LEFT,
>   RIGHT, and FULL outer joins. It not only boasts of handling unlimited
>   nesting of Sub-queries, it handles them in every major clause (SELECT,
>   FROM, WHERE, JOIN, ON, HAVING, even GROUP BY!). Speaking of grouping,
>   it also handles grouping sets, rollup, cube, and grand-total grouping
>   functions. It even gracefully handles complex conditional expressions
>   such as:
>
> (a,b) not in ((1, 2), (3, 4), (select c, d from tab))
>
> Add into this the ability AT RUNTIME to mix in custom, user-defined
>   functions and third party tables (two cool features in their own
>   right), and the SQL engine is truly extraordinary. No other SQL engine
>   can do these things, let alone do it 100% in JavaScript across all
>   major browsers and platforms. And, let’s not forget that it does all
>   this with blazingly fast speed: parsing, planning, and optimizing all
>   occurring sub-millisecond.

For full disclosure:  I am part of SequelSphere, and the product is awesome.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input. I have looked at this and it seems to be a good solution. A couple of things, is this stable / tested - it seems to be new and it does not say how well test it is. 2nd - how much is it for an app the maybe sold ?

Comment: The latest "Stable" release, Version 1.2.1 is very stable and well tested.  Edge Releases do go through numerous (thousands) of automated tests across all major browsers prior to being published.  Nevertheless, the Edge is the bleeding edge.  Concerning Price:  Email "support@ Sequ ... com" for more details, or email me:  "john.fowler@ Sequ ... com"

Comment: Link is dead --- does SequelSphere still exist anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Try my open source library https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/wiki/Home It has IndexedDB, WebSQL and web storage. Rich query options are provided. Surprisingly easy to use.